# Can I make an Amazon AWS Lamda function which is triggered by the creation of an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to send a mail when a new bucket is created on our AWS account. I'd prefer this to be near-instantaneous so preferably not time scheduled, but triggered by the CreatBucket event directly.

When I try to create a new function and configure an S3 trigger, the bucket selection is mandatory

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, please read description of [tag:amazon-web-services]

Comment: Can you suggest where might be more appropriate? I have received a helpful reply below and similar questions around around similar vmware functionality appear to be allowable on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

As [@michael-sqlbot](https://superuser.com/users/183147/michael-sqlbot) has pointed out in the comments, what you are trying to achieve may be possible but with a multi-step process. CloudTrail can log S3 bucket-level events (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) including bucket creation, it can then be configured to generate CloudWatch events, and finally you can use specific CloudWatch events as triggers for Lambda.

---

This isn't *directly* supported, here is the list of all events that can be generated by S3:

- `s3:ObjectCreated:*`
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Post`
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Copy`
- `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload`

> Amazon S3 APIs such as PUT, POST, and COPY can create an object. Using these event types, you can enable notification when an object is created using a specific API, or you can use the s3:ObjectCreated:* event type to request notification regardless of the API that was used to create an object.
>
> You will not receive event notifications from failed operations.

- `s3:ObjectRemoved:*`
- `s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete`
- `s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated`

> By using the ObjectRemoved event types, you can enable notification when an object or a batch of objects is removed from a bucket.
>
> You can request notification when an object is deleted or a versioned object is permanently deleted by using the s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete event type. Or you can request notification when a delete marker is created for a versioned object by using s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated. For information about deleting versioned objects, see Deleting Object Versions. You can also use a wildcard s3:ObjectRemoved:* to request notification anytime an object is deleted.
>
> You will not receive event notifications from automatic deletes from lifecycle policies or from failed operations.

- `s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject`

> You can use this event type to request Amazon S3 to send a notification message when Amazon S3 detects that an object of the RRS storage class is lost.

All events work at an object level, requiring the bucket exist.

**Source:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I've updated the answer with more detail.

Comment: Is this your final answer?  AWS CloudTrail can capture S3 bucket creation API calls: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-supported-services.html#cloudtrail-supported-services-storage-and-content-delivery

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm reviewing that doc this morning, it looks like it may be exactly what I need

Comment: This works SNS to send a quick and dirty email and could be tided up to generate an email in node.js. This will do the job. Thanks